# How can I resolve these err msgs following a TFS "Get Latest Version (Recursion)"?

Tags: tfs, compact-framework, resx, visual-studio-2003, xp-mode

I was able to compile and run an .exe built in XP Mode with Visual Studio 2003. I then noticed the version of the source I was using was not up to date (based on a version number string). So I did a "Get Latest Version (Recursion)"

That gave me the correct version number, but also over 100 Build Errors, of thes types:

Two of these, but 2-clicking them goes nowhere:

"*Error reading resources from the resource file for the default culture: Invalid ResX input.  Could not find valid "resheader" tags for the .NET Compact Framework ResX reader & writer type names.  Make sure this Resx file is a .NET Compact Framework Resx file.*"

Dozens of these; 2-clicking them also takes me nowhere:

"*Object type cannot be converted to target type.*"

10 or a dozen of these:
"*Resource transformation for file 'frmAbout.resx' failed.  Invalid ResX input.  Could not find valid "resheader" tags for the .NET Compact Framework ResX reader & writer type names.  Make sure this Resx file is a .NET Compact Framework Resx file.*"

2-clicking those gave me this nice "Data for Data" grid:

[image]

Finally, several like this:

"*'PDAClient.PrinterPickerForm' does not contain a definition for 'AutoScaleMode'*"

...which take me to code like this:

this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Inherit;

Why would simply getting the latest version of code cause all this mayhem?

Comment: Does the latest version run for others? Is it possible that someone checked in some bad code?

Comment: Which TFS version?  You're certain all files got checked in?

Comment: @DeanOC: " Is it possible that someone checked in some bad code?" That's always possible. But the cat who last checked in code has absquatulated (left for another job). "...run for others." Nobody else has tried to run it; have to get it running on the device before they could.

Comment: @ctacke: "Which TFS version?" I don't know what version TFS it is, or how to determine that. With the project open in VS 2003, the File menu has a Source Control submenu item with a "Team Foundation Properties..." sub-submenu item, but it has no info about that.